# Pattern attribute HTML not matching regex

Tags: html, regex

So I have this line of code :

```html
<form>
<input max="250" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 \.\,\!\?\:\[\]\(\)\"\-\+]+" 
class="inputBox" type="text" id="comment" name="CommentContent" placeholder="write here">
</form>
```

but it doesn't seem to match anything at all.

I got it to work for more simple regex but not for this one.

I used a site to validate it and it looks like it's valid.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: @ZiTAL submitted an edit (the user didn't use proper markup) ; wait until it's peer reviewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the wrapping quote and don't escape the chars other than the []

```html
<form>
<input max="250" required pattern='[A-Za-z0-9 .,!?:\[\]()"-+]+' 
class="inputBox" type="text" id="comment" name="CommentContent" placeholder="write here">
</form>
```